# Dot product of 2 vectors C++

Tags: c++, floating-point

I have to write the program that will output dot product of two vectors.

> Organise the calculations using only Double type to get the most accurate result as it is possible.
>
> How input should look like:
>
> ```
>    N - vector length
>    x1, x2,..., xN      co-ordinates of vector x (double type)
>    y1, y2,..., yN      co-ordinates of vector y (double type)
> ```
>
> Sample of input:
>
> ```
>    4
>    1.0e20 -1.0e3 0.1 1.0e20
>    1.0 4.0 -4.0 -1.0
> ```
>
> Output for vectors above:
>
> ```
>    -4000.4
> ```

And there is my code (I didn't use cin yet because at first I wanted to write working program with samples inputs):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

int main(){
//double N; //length of both vectors , will be used when I will have to input vectors by cin
//std::cin >> N;
//N = 4;

std::vector<double> x{1.0e20, -1.0e3, 0.1, 1.0e20};
std::vector<double> y{1.0, 4.0, -4.0, -1.0};
double result = std::inner_product(x.begin(), x.end(), y.begin(), 0);

std::cout << result;
return 0;
}
```

My output is -2.14748e+09 so its not even close to the expected one. What should I do to make it works?

Comment: Try inspecting the result of each multiplication and the partial sum at each step, I strongly suspect a floating point precision problem.

Comment: Overflow or precision problem.

Comment: It should be `std::inner_product(x.begin(), x.end(), y.begin(), 0.0);`. Note the double literal `0.0` instead of the int literal 0 as the last argument.

Comment: To get the most accurate result possible you need to be careful with the order in which you sum the products.

Comment: `double N; //length of both vectors` length should be an integer, not double. The "standard" length type is `size_t`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The (first) problem

This is the function template for the inner product in `<numeric>`:

```
template <class InputIterator1, class InputIterator2, class T>
   T inner_product (InputIterator1 first1, InputIterator1 last1,
                    InputIterator2 first2, T init);
```

Notice that what defines the type `T` of the output is the `init` parameter. So, given your input:

```
std::inner_product(x.begin(), x.end(), y.begin(), 0);
```

`init = 0`, therefore the type `T` is `int`. So, when the algorithm runs, it will typecast the `double` values into `int`s which, ultimately, will return an undefined `int` value.

### A "fix" and the second problem

**To fix the problem**, all you have to do is give a properly-typed `init` value(that is, give a `double` as the `init` parameter). Just `0.0` will do:

```
std::inner_product(x.begin(), x.end(), y.begin(), 0.0);
```

Now, when you compile and run the program with that fix, **it will still output an incorrect result**: `0`

This is because when the `inner_product` function accumulates the values, it does so using standard `double` addition. Therefore, you are subject to standard `double` imprecision, [which has a machine epsilon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) of 2^(-52) — 2.22E-16 or about an imprecision in the sixteenth decimal place — which implies, for the number 1E20, that (1E20 + x) = 1E20 for all x < 2^(-52)*1E20 ≈ 22204.46.

**To illustrate the point**, let's add `1E20 + 23000` in the python interpreter(reminder that python uses [IEEE-754 floating point arithmetic](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#representation-error), which is equal to the precision of `double` in a standard C++ compiler):

```
>>> 1e20 + 23000
1.0000000000000002e+20
```

So you see that anything less than twenty thousand was ignored/"absorbed" in the addition.

Since your other numbers are less than 22204.46, the 1e20 will just "absorb" them until it gets added to -1E20, which will then "cancel out" and return `0`.

### The (easy) fix

The easiest way to fix this second problem is to use `long double` instead of `double`. This more precise double-precision type has a machine epsilon of 2^(-63) — 1.08E-19 or about nineteeen decimal places — which means that, for your input 1E20, the imprecision will be equal to 2^(-63)*1E20, or about 10.84. Running the program, the output will be `-4000`, which is quite close to the expected answer. **But that's probably not what your professor expects**, since he specifically requests the output to be *precisely* `-4000.4`.

Note: obviously, you could go for another, more precise numeric type, but your professor probably expects you to use `double`, so I won't go into detail in that.

**Edit:** as [@phuclv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/995714/phuclv) mentioned in the comments, [some compilers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/9cx8xs15(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) don't implement `long double` as 80-bit floating-point values, but instead may have the same precision as a `double`(64-bit). So you might have to look for libraries that provide proper 80-bit precision `long double`s or even [128-bit IEEE-754 quadruple-precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format) floating point types. Though that *definitely* would not be considered "easy".

### The (mostly correct) fix

Well, you can't be infinitely precise, because the `double` type has epsilon = 2^(-52), but you can be smarter in the addition, without just adding big values to small ones(*remember: the big values "absorb" small ones because of imprecision in the `double` floating-point arithmetic*). Basically, you should calculate an array that has the pairwise multiplication of the values, then sort it(**based on the absolute value**) then add the values using `std::accumulate`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
//Mind the use of these two new STL libraries
#include <algorithm> //std::sort and std::transform
#include <cmath> //abs()



int main(){

    std::vector<double> x{1.0e20, -1.0e3, 0.1, 1.0e20};
    std::vector<double> y{1.0, 4.0, -4.0, -1.0};
    //The vector with the pairwise products
    std::vector<double> products(x.size());

    //Do element-wise multiplication
    //C code: products[i] += x[i] * y[i];
    std::transform(x.begin(), x.end(), y.begin(), products.begin(), std::multiplies<double>());

    //Sort the array based on absolute-value
    auto sort_abs = [] (double a, double b) { return abs(a) < abs(b); };
    std::sort(products.begin(), products.end(), sort_abs);

    //Add the values of the products(note the init=0.0)
    double result = std::accumulate(products.begin(), products.end(), 0.0);

    std::cout << result << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

With this new code, the result is as expected: `-4000.4`

Tough it obviously has it's limitations. For example, if the input was the vectors v1 = {100.0, 1E20} and v2 = {10.0, 1.0}, which should return `100000000000000001000` as a result, will obviously just return 1E20.

Comment: note that `long double` isn't guaranteed to have bigger precision than `double`. For example on MSVC and (almost) all microcontrollers they have the same precision

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I understand how it should works. I forgot about limits of  Double. Finally I got to know something more about vectors.

Comment: @phuclv Oh thank you, did not know that. I'll add that to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

There are a logical error and some numeric issues in the posted snippet.

- [`std::inner_product`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inner_product) Initializes the accumulator with the initial value passed, so it uses the same type for it a and for the returned value. The posted code uses an integer, `0`, while a floating point value, like `0.0` should be used.
- The values in the vectors have an extremely wide range of magnitudes. A floating point type like `double` has a finite precision, it can't represent every possible real number without rounding errors. Also (and because of that) floating point math operations are not associative and sensitive to the order in which they are performed.

To picture it, you can [run](https://godbolt.org/z/6Ynj19) the following snippet.

```
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <fmt/core.h> // fmt::print

int main()
{
    using vec4d = std::array<double, 4>;
    
    vec4d x{1.0e20, 1.0e20, -1.0e3, 0.1};
    vec4d y{1.0, -1.0, 4.0, -4.0};
    
    vec4d z;
    std::transform( std::begin(x), std::end(x), std::begin(y), std::begin(z)
                  , std::multiplies<double>{} );
    std::sort(std::begin(z), std::end(z));

    fmt::print("{0:>{1}}\n", "sum", 44);
    fmt::print("{0:->{1}}", '\n', 48);
    do {
        for (auto i : z) {
            fmt::print("{0:8}", i);
        }
        auto sum{ std::accumulate(std::begin(z), std::end(z), 0.0) };
        fmt::print("{0:{1}.{2}f}\n", sum, 14, 1);
    } while ( std::next_permutation(std::begin(z), std::end(z)) );
}
```

Here is its output:

```
                                         sum
-----------------------------------------------
  -1e+20   -4000    -0.4   1e+20           0.0
  -1e+20   -4000   1e+20    -0.4          -0.4
  -1e+20    -0.4   -4000   1e+20           0.0
  -1e+20    -0.4   1e+20   -4000       -4000.0
  -1e+20   1e+20   -4000    -0.4       -4000.4
  -1e+20   1e+20    -0.4   -4000       -4000.4
   -4000  -1e+20    -0.4   1e+20           0.0
   -4000  -1e+20   1e+20    -0.4          -0.4
   -4000    -0.4  -1e+20   1e+20           0.0
   -4000    -0.4   1e+20  -1e+20           0.0
   -4000   1e+20  -1e+20    -0.4          -0.4
   -4000   1e+20    -0.4  -1e+20           0.0
    -0.4  -1e+20   -4000   1e+20           0.0
    -0.4  -1e+20   1e+20   -4000       -4000.0
    -0.4   -4000  -1e+20   1e+20           0.0
    -0.4   -4000   1e+20  -1e+20           0.0
    -0.4   1e+20  -1e+20   -4000       -4000.0
    -0.4   1e+20   -4000  -1e+20           0.0
   1e+20  -1e+20   -4000    -0.4       -4000.4
   1e+20  -1e+20    -0.4   -4000       -4000.4
   1e+20   -4000  -1e+20    -0.4          -0.4
   1e+20   -4000    -0.4  -1e+20           0.0
   1e+20    -0.4  -1e+20   -4000       -4000.0
   1e+20    -0.4   -4000  -1e+20           0.0
```

Note that the "correct" answer, -4000.4, only occurs when the bigger terms (1e+20 and -1e+20) cancel out in the *first* summation. This is an artifact due to the particular numbers chosen as inputs, where the two biggest ones are *equal* in terms of magnitude and also have opposite sign. In general subctracting two numbers that are *almost* the some leads to catastrophic cancellation and loss of significance.

The next best result, -4000.0, happens when the smaller value in terms of magnitude, 0.4, is "near" the biggest ones and it's canceled out.

Various techiniques can be adopted to reduce the amount of growing numerical errors when summing many terms, like [pairwise summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_summation) or compensated summation (see e.g. [Kahan summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm)).

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/Kf8vGG), I tested Neumaier summation with the same samples.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now it's much easier to undestand how it works.